# Copying php from inside html page to external

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am making a simple chatting service, but to be able to autorefresh the page, a need to move the php script to an external page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat_innhold">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#chat_innhold').load('Content/chat_innhold.php');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout ( function() {
        $('#chat_innhold').fadeOut('slow').load('Content/chat_innhold.php').fadeIn('slow');
        refresh();
    }, 200);
    }
</script>   
    </div //chat_innhold>
```

**External php**

```
<?php do { ?>
  <div id="chat" <?php if ($row_chatinnhold['chat_id'] !== '3') {
    echo 'hidden';} ?>>
    <div id="<?php
    if (strtolower($row_chatinnhold['brukernavn']) == strtolower($_SESSION['MM_Username']) ) {
    echo 'chatnavn_login';}
    else {
    echo 'chatnavn'; }
    ?>" style="color: <?php
    echo $row_chatinnhold['farge'];
    ?>"><?php if ($row_chatinnhold['chat_id'] == '3'){
    echo $row_chatinnhold['brukernavn'];} ?>
    <br />
    </div //chatnavn>
    <div id="chatchat_wrap">
      <div id="<?php
    if (strtolower($row_chatinnhold['brukernavn']) == strtolower($_SESSION['MM_Username'])){
    echo 'chatchat_login';}
    else {
    echo 'chatchat'; }
    ?>" ><?php if ($row_chatinnhold['chat_id'] == '3') {
    echo $row_chatinnhold['chat'];} ?>
        <br />
      </div //chatchat>
    </div //chatchat_wrap>
  </div //chat>
    <?php } while ($row_chatinnhold = mysql_fetch_assoc($chatinnhold)); ?>
```

How can i get this to work? Do i need to specify the sql tables in the external php, and the login in script? I know my coding is kinda messy, but i hope you are able to see my point :)

Comment: Given that you can autorefresh a page with either html or javascript, why do you have to move anything?

Comment: I actually found the problem, had to include the conection to the mysql database in the external php script:)